# Which Tesla Roadster was launched into space?

Tags: spacex, tesla-roadster

Which Roadster was launched into space? What year was it made? I cannot find any information about it. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk%27s_Tesla_Roadster#Background), there is an image of it from 2010, so it is at least that old. It doesn't look like P1, which as far as I know, wasn't red.

Is there any information about which roadster it was?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Elon Musk Tesla Roadster]

A [Tesla Roadster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Roadster) was launched into space in February, 2018 on a SpaceX [Falcon Heavy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_Heavy) rocket as a test payload. This vehicle was a first generation [2008-model Tesla Roadster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Roadster_(first_generation)). The car was personally owned by Elon Musk and used previously for commuting to work. The attached photo of Starman and the Roadster are from SpaceX shot with a camera attached to the front of the car capturing the Earth in the background.

The Roadster was the ninth car launched into space. The first being Lunokhod 0, which crashed on landing in February, 1969. Other vehicles include Lunokhod 1-2, [Apollo Lunar Roving Vehicle (Moon Buggy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Roving_Vehicle), Prop-M, Sojourner, Mars Exploration Rover Spirit, Lunar Rover Yutu and Mars Exploration Rover Opportunity, which all launched before the Tesla Roadster. Some of these vehicles never operated, but then again, neither did the Roadster.

As far as the color, I would suggest being the CEO of Tesla might come with privileges, like choosing your own color.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elon_Musk%27s_Tesla_Roadster
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rover_(space_exploration)

Comment: Being CEO of Tesla could also come with other privileges, such as owning more than one Roadster. If you look [here](https://www.tesla.com/en_AU/blog/re-p1-arriving-now), P1, the first production Tesla Roadster, is clearly black. Is it known if the Tesla Roadster launched into space was P1 (painted), or another Roadster Elon had?

Comment: Is the LRV really a "production car"? I don't think it's street legal...

Comment: @Dragongeek At least nine LRVs were produced, three flew to the moon, one scrapped for parts, the others used as test vehicles. No effort went into making them street legal because they were never designed for any other mission than driving on the moon. I removed the word production and added the fact that the Tesla, despite what Spacex says, was the ninth vehicle launched into space. It is by definition the most produced  production vehicle in space.